# Send Ctrl-Alt-Del over SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access

I know that Linux may, depending on configuration, allow the interactive user to reboot the server by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> even without logging in. I have a **remote console** session over SSH to a remote server that I cannot log into, but I want to reboot it. Is it possible to somehow send the key combination <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> over SSH (or `telnet`)? If so, how?

**Edit:** to clarify, I am not just connected to the server's `sshd` over `ssh` - I am connected via a KVM over IP switch, so it's a serial console. But this connection itself is over SSH and my question is how to send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> key combination over it.

Comment: Read your KVM documentation. It should have a way to invoke keychords, especially given you have to use Ctrl-Alt-Del to log into Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are connected to a serial console and your kernel has `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ` and `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` enabled (default on my Ubuntu machines), you can try <kbd>BREAK</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>BREAK</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>BREAK</kbd> (depends on the `SSH` to serial converter).

If that works, you can press <kbd>h</kbd> (within 5 seconds) to get a list of available commands ("`s = sync filesystems`" and "`b = force immediate reboot`" are maybe what you are looking for).

For more information, have a look at [linux/Documentation/sysrq.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/Documentation/sysrq.txt)

Comment: SSH's built-in "send break" may work too.  It's "~B"  (tilde-b).

Comment: Good to know about this, but didn't work in this particular case. :( I guess it's not enabled.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Sysrq trigger in order to make an immediate reset (it's like pressing ALT-BREAK-b):

`echo b >/proc/sysrq-trigger`

BEFORE that, you might want to sync all filesystems, to not lose any data:

`echo s >/proc/sysrq-trigger`

This might only work if CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ is enabled in your kernel. The possible keys are explained at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) btw.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you mention (ttyS0) - this isn't the local console, it's a serial console.

I don't think you can do Ctrl-Alt-Del from the serial console.

http://osdir.com/ml/linux.hardware.dell.poweredge/2003-01/msg00200.html suggests a way getting magic-sysrq working over serial - maybe this would be sufficient for rebooting a server?

Comment: Yep, sorry - serial console. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The three-fingered reboot is only available from a local console.

It is handled by the following inittab line:

```
# What to do at the "Three Finger Salute".
ca:12345:ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

You would need to use the `shutdown`, `halt` or `reboot` commands from a shell with root privileges instead, if you don't have physical access to the machine.

Comment: Thanks, but I am at the local console (ttyS0) - just remotely over a KVM-IP device, which uses SSH.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Do you know the make/model of KVM? I would have thought it provided a break-out menu for such escape sequences.

Comment: No, I don't know the model - it's provided by the DC. I suspect there's one KVM for multiple machines, too, so I don't have full access to it, only to my server.

Comment: I would hazard then that it is probably not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Look into a remote KVM switch to reboot without SSH access. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#Remote_KVM_devices

Comment: I am connected over a remote KVM device - but I don't know how to make it reboot the server. I don't have any menu or anything, I just see the server's screen (in text mode, of course).

Comment: What is the brand/model of KVM?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the command has been disabled?  I regularly disable it on my production servers, usually to protect them from me when I forget that I'm logging into a Linux machine instead of a Windows machine and accidentally press Ctrl-Alt-Del and subsequently reboot the machine.

On machines which I do leave it so that a non-technical person can reboot, I extend the time in Dan's example from "now" to "2 minutes" so there's a sliver of a chance the reboot can be aborted if needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the username/password of the remote machine, you can use SysInternals [PSShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) command to reboot a remote computer.  Note, if you have gone to the trouble of forcing SSH to a KVM, your server is probably setup so that you can't reboot machines without logging in.  In fact, its the default for servers from MS, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I doubt that a Windows utility would have worked on a *Linux* server. :)

Answer (score -2):

Isn't it easier to just issue "shutdown -h now", "reboot" or "halt" on the command line depending on what you prefer to happen to the machine?

Comment: He said that he is unable to login to the the server, so I don't think that will work. I also don't think he will be ablt to use ctrl-alt-del either

Comment: Allowing ctrl-alt-del over a non-logged in SSH session sounds like a horrible idea!  Just think, you'd be able to reboot *any* server you could open an SSH connection with!